# Why is this snippet of code refusing to resize my div trough javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
if(document.getElementById("scroll_dr_fise").offsetHeight > document.getElementById("col_dr_scroll").offsetHeight) {                   
    alert(document.getElementById("col_dr_scroll").offsetHeight);                        
    document.getElementById("scroll_dr_fise").style.height = document.getElementById("col_dr_scroll").offsetHeight+"px";                    
    alert(document.getElementById("scroll_dr_fise").style.height);                  
    document.getElementById("scroll_dr_fise").style.overflowY = "scroll";                   
}
```

I'm trying to use this code to resize the height of "scroll_dr_fise" to the height of "col_dr_scroll" whenever the first is bigger than the second and to add a vertical scroll to "col_dr_fise".

So far it adds the scroll but it doesn't resize the div at all.

The outputs of the echoes are "500" and "500" as you would expect.

Comment: What type of element is `#scroll_dr_fise`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just have your assignments upside down or looking the other way.
If I got it right:
You want to resize col_dr_scroll to the same height as scroll_dr_fise, if scroll_dr_fise is taller than col_dr_scroll.

But in your assignment, you're actually setting colxxxx's offset height to xxxdr_fise. and setting the scroll to the fise one as well :S

Solution: just swap the ids within the block i.e. if (xxx > yyy) { swap em here }

Sidenote: If you're accessing the same node three or four times, it would be better if you selected it and saved it to a var and used the var rather than selecting it every single time. Will improve performance and will make your code look sexier.

Comment: sorry, the code is in the correct order, wrote it the wrong way around in the description. Changed it now.